# How do I tell if an NPC is essential?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I received the "Lights out!" quest from Jaree-Ra, but it does not match with the personality of my characters.
Since I cannot report him to any guard or other authority, I decided to kill him without doing the quest in order to see what happens. However, I assume that he is marked as essential.

How can i check if an NPC is marked as essential or not **without dropping them to low HP before realizing they cannot be killed**?
Console commands are an option.

I know there is a console command to set them to non-essential but I am specifically trying to check their essential status in advance.

Comment: why do you not want to kill him? so he isn't mad at you?

Comment: @Dragonrage I do want to kill him, i just dont want to do the quest. i dont want to start killing him to find out i cant.

Comment: i was talking about this "without killing them to low hp and then realizing "o crap i cant kill him.." in particular. do you not want to attack them and realize they wont die, and they then will attack you and you wont be able to kill them? you can kill (try to kill) them without causing them to retaliate. would that solve your problem?

Comment: Save, attempt to kill, load

Comment: @Dragonrage i'm not sure i understand what you mean, am i unclear on something in my question?

Comment: @DCShannon yes that is an option but does require mt to go through the killing process to test essential status.

Comment: i'm just wondering why you don't want to attempt to kill to determine if they are essential, as there are several ways to do it without taking hardly anytime, or causing the person to try to attack you

Comment: I just want to know if there are other ways, easier or faster ways to determine this.

Comment: if you are using the console it takes all of a half a second to kill the person. open console, click on the person, type kill, hit enter, close console. if they are not lying on the ground dead, they are essential. pretty quick and easy. if this works for you, i can make it an answer.

Comment: @Dragonrage that is indeed a nice way to check and sort of avoids the combat

Comment: You'll still need to use the console to remove the "talk to Jaree-Ra" miscellaneous objective, unless you accept the quest before killing him.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Targeted_Commands) of Skyrim console commands, you can select the NPC in question (generally using your cursor) and enter the command `IsEssential` which will return 1.00 if they are, in fact, essential.

> Related functions: To check whether an NPC is essential to begin with, select him/her in the console (so that the ref ID appears), and enter IsEssential - if the console returns "1.00", the NPC is essential.

Comment: the simple answer i was looking for; tested and works

Comment: Related: If you don't mind breaking the set quest pattern, you can use `SetEssential 0` which makes the NPC killable.

Answer (score 34):

If you have 100 points in Pickpocketing and the perk that allows you to pickpocket equipped items, you can test them. You will not be able to remove equipped items on essential NPCs, even with the trait.

Source: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs

Comment: +1 because this would be a good way to check on consoles where commands are not an option

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this using the console is to use the kill command on them. You avoid combat, and if you want them dead and they aren't essential they will be dead. Otherwise they will lay on the ground for awhile. To use the kill command open the console and click on the target then type kill and hit enter.